# Scala Worksheet Intellij not evaluating results properly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am running this scala code in IntelliJ Worksheet.

```
object sheet3 {
  println("Welcome to new worksheet")
  val nums = new Array[Int](10)
  for (i <- 0 until nums.length) nums(i) = i * i
  nums
  val a = Array("Hello", "Friend")

  a(0) = "Goodbye"
  println(a)

  for (i <- 0.until(a.length)) print(i)

}
```

However, I am getting this result
[image: Results]

I was hoping for this instead when I run in scala repl

```
scala> val nums = new Array[Int](10)
nums: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Thanks for the help

**Additional Problem**

```
object reply extends App{
  println("Welcome world")
  val words = Array("Marry", "had", "a", "little", "lamb", "its", "fleece",
    "was", "white", "as", "snow")
  println(words.groupBy(_.substring(0, 1)))
  println(words.mkString(" "))
}
```

Results below

```
 Welcome world
    s -> [Ljava.lang.String;@32e6e9c3 f -> [Ljava.lang.String;@2669b199 a -> [Ljava.lang.String;@2344fc66 M -> [Ljava.lang.String;@458ad742 i -> [Ljava.lang.String;@5afa04c l -> [Ljava.lang.String;@6ea12c19 h -> [Ljava.lang.String;@6a024a67 w -> [Ljava.lang.String;@7921b0a2
    Marry had a little lamb its fleece was white as snow

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In code above, how can I get the results to print Strings instead of java.lang.String;@32e6e9c3. 
Was unsuccessful when tried with `println(words.groupBy(_.substring(0, 1)).mkString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your 2nd question is much like the answer to the 1st.  The problem is that you're using `Array` which implements the ugly Java `toString`.  If you used a Scala collection like `Seq`, `Vector`, or `List`, you'd see a cleaner output.

Since the `groupBy()` output is a `Map[String, Array[String]]`, you're going to have to reach into the map's values before applying `mkString` to the `Array`.

This is one way ...

```
println(words.groupBy(_.substring(0, 1)).mapValues(_.mkString))
```

... but it's a little more idiomatic (and perhaps easier to read the output) if you do it this way ...

```
words.groupBy(_.substring(0, 1)).mapValues(_.mkString).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

In scala, `Array[T]` are just a representation for java's `T[]`. In particular, they inherit the Java implementation of `toString`, which result is something like `[I@233fa27`.

The more usual way to print the content of an Array is to use `mkString`:

```
scala>   val nums = new Array[Int](10)
nums: Array[Int] = [I@119ad2c5

scala> nums.mkString(",")
res1: String = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However did you have an idea how to solve a similar problem I had. I added it in my original question. Thanks very much